# Cannot play offline video in production electron app

Tags: electron

I have an electron/ember app that allows users to store a video offline and play it later. The ember app uses a `video` tag with a computed property to swap out the video src from the server with the offline link. I am storing it using `electron.getPath("userData")` so for macOS it's in `~/Library/Application Support/<appname>`. The problem comes when I create the signed distributable. The offline support works just fine when running with `ember electron` but as soon as a I sign and package it for release it no longer works. The video player itself loads but is just blank. Is there some limitation with using local files in release mode for electron?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is https://github.com/electron/electron-compile/pull/199

tldr; skip authenticity checks on local files

```
const { app } = require("electron");
const { addBypassChecker } = require('electron-compile');

addBypassChecker((filePath) => {
  return filePath.indexOf(app.getAppPath()) === -1;
});
```